# How to update all documents based on whether an array contains a specific element in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I have been trying with this:

```
self.followersDbRef.update({'followersList':{'$elemMatch':{'$eq':userID}}},{'$addToSet':{'feed':postDict},'$set':{'_id':userID}},multi=True,upsert=True)
```

but to no avail.
Instead another document is created altogether.

It should be such that whenever I add a post all other users that follow me will get the post copied to their feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoDB the basic query `{ key: "value" }` matches both for exact match and for match within an array. So if your data looks like this:

```json
{"key": "a"},
{"key": ["a", "b"]}
```

Then the following query will match both documents:

```js
db.collection.find({"key": "a"})
```

With that in mind, this is probably what you're looking for:

```py
self.followersDbRef.update(
  {'followersList': userID},
  {'$addToSet': {'feed':postDict},'$set':{'_id':userID}},
  multi=True,
  upsert=True
)
```

Also note that `upsert` means that if no match is found, a document will be inserted instead. If you do not want that to happen, you can remove `upsert=True` or change it to `False`.